"One who does not waste time, has time for everything" - learning on Shabbos
The Chida, in his Moreh BeEtzba (153) writes basically that on Shabbos, ones occupation should solely be Limud HaTorah. He says,

כי לא נתנו שבתות וי״ט אלא ללמוד תורה. ומי שאינו מאבד הזמן יש עת לכל
One who does not waste time, has time for eveything

Are there seforim that explain the great advantage of learning Torah on Shabbos specifically?
I recall learning a Ben Ish Chai that says that one hour learning on Shabbos, is like learning a whole week.

Seems pretty self-explanatory. There's time enough for everything, as long as you don't waste time. What are you stuck on?

See here for similar comments regarding not wasting time on frivolity on shabbos.

I saw once the list for what the Chida would learn on Rosh Hashana. It would take most people probably a month.

י-ה אכסוף נועם שבת המתאמת ומייחדת בסגולתך. משוך נועם יראתך לעם מבקשי רצונך. קדשם בקדושת השבת המתאחדת בתורתך. פתח להם נועם ורצון לפתוח שערי רצונך.

@Shmosel I was wondering what it meant in the context the Chida wrote it in.

Ben Ish Chai (Year 2, Shemos) writes: “Learning on Shabbos is worth 1000 times more than learning during the week”

@LaniedSofey TY, that is the one I remember yes. But why is this especially?
